# Why using the actionbar instead of custom header view?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

Even set gravity of title text we must use

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

So why should I use actionbar instead of custom header view?

Comment: Action-bar can be more manageable that custom headerView.

Comment: Action bar generally required when implementing navigation drawer

Comment: @JIGAR my problem is "why should I use actionbar instead of custom header xml" ? if i create header.xml and add all activity layout. what make action bar differance header.xml

Comment: @VivekMishra , in my case i want to make 2 type header view 1.view centered title with back button ,2. view only centered logo , i have to 2 custom xml. iis it unnecessary for me?

Comment: @user2859375 No then you do not require action bar.And in that case just include your action bar layout in xml file where you want to use it

Comment: @VivekMishra thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can search for android design guideline from Google.
In this guidelines you can read that :

> Using the app bar makes your app consistent with other Android apps, allowing users to quickly understand how to operate your app and have a great experience.

This means that using action bar, you will use the back buttons or the drawer for instance, the same way as the other app.

Comment: when i using getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar); i cant use actionbar's back button , in my case i want to make 2 type header view 1.view  centered title with back button ,2. view only  centered logo , i have to 2 custom xml. what is my advantage using actionbar?